# Structure of IPv6 DNS record

Tags: dns, ipv6

I am looking for the specifications / the description of an IPv6 DNS record. I have found this document:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

which fully describes the structure of an IPv4 DNS record, but I can't find the equivalent for IPv6. Is there an RFC or a description for that ?

Comment: close voters - this would appear to be on topic if you want to know how to implement a AAAA record in your own software.

Comment: No, I just want to learn how to send a DNS request and read back the response. I made a fully functional software to query IPV4 DNS. Now I would like to make it for IPV6 also. I know such software is useless. There is already nslookup. But I just want to learn programming. So the best I can do is have some projects that interest me. Most of the time, new programming learners have projects that are way to hard for them, and they get replies such as "that's too advanced for you". Start with something easier. This is me following this kind of advice.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPV6 is just an extension. To find info on them its easiest to search for "DNS AAAA record".

Here is the RFC you requested:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3596.txt

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. How did you find it ?

Comment: The definitive way of finding any RR type is to look in the link I gave.  You do of course need to know that the IPv6 record type is actually called `AAAA`.

Comment: which I didn't know... thank you !

Answer (score 5):

The record type for an IPv6 record is known as a `AAAA` record.  It's defined in [RFC 3596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3596).

IANA [maintains a registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xml#dns-parameters-3) of which RFC document specifies each RR type - they're all indexed there.

NB: there's also an `A6` record for IPv6 which predates `AAAA` which but it was made obsolete by [RFC 6353](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6563).